# How to make UIImageView slide into View Controllers main view - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

So I have an imageView of a character that I want to start off screen and slide into my view controllers main view once a user presses a button. I've been trying to accomplish this my altering the multiplier and constants on with Auto Layout, but I can't seem to get it right. I was thinking that there had to be a better way...thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add your image view to a view which fills the area of the screen the image has to animate over.

Assign leading and top constraints to your image view relative to the superview.

If using IB, CTRL drag these constraints into your controller header file to create IBOutlets for them. If doing all this in code, create these in `viewDidLoad`.

Initialize the `constant` value of the constraints to position the image outside of the containing view.

To bring the image on screen, do the following in your button handler.

```
// ... Set the leading constraint value to where you want the image
// ... Set the top constraint value to where you want the image

// Mark as needing layout
[self.theImageContainterView setNeedsLayout];

// Animate the layout change
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
     [self.theImageContainerView layoutIfNeeded];
   } completion:nil];
```

As shown this will animate the image to its new position in 2 seconds. You can add a completion handler to deal with any completion actions needed when the animation finishes.